# Brahma giving boons to asuras

Tags: brahma

Why did asuras like Ravana, Narakasura, Kansa, Tarakasura pray to Brahma only and why did Brahma give so many boons to them?

Shouldn't the asuras not be given any boons knowing that they are asuras?

Comment: Because Brahma was father to all. Vishnu was famous as trickster and shiva was for his anger in Stayuga. So in Satyuga mostly all the tapa was done fro brahma.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Why Shiva was angry in Satya Yuga?

Comment: Brahma represents Rajo guna (intense activity, passion). Asuras, by their nature are drawn to such modes of tapas like crucifying their body. Brahma is very pleased by it and grants boons to them. Later, Vishnu takes avatars and destroys them. He also warns Brahma to take care when giving boons (e.g. after Hiranya vadham)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Lord Shiva fulfill wishes of evil people also?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/why-does-lord-shiva-fulfill-wishes-of-evil-people-also)