# Why doesn't God not give us anything without doing something?

Tags: scripture, gods, worship, mantras, bhakti

In Hinduism there are cases where astrologers or pandits ask devotees to chant certain mantras or do fasting on specific days. Why doesn't God give what we want directly (without doing anything) as we are God's children?

Comment: The basic few things needed to sustain life and which can not be created by us are given for free by God for everyones' use viz-air,water,light etc.Astrologers suggest remedies for curing Graha doshas present in our horoscopes.Even those remedies were created by God and are mentioned in our scriptures.We create the doshas by our own bad karmas but the compassionate and ever forgiving Lord has even provided remedies so that we may suffer less.

Comment: Related in opposite way: [Why does Lord Shiva fulfill wishes of evil people also?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5378/1049). It will be good, if you can edit your answer bit more to clarify what exactly is the query. As the other answer suggest, as of now it's too broad. May be you can put some examples.

Comment: Very good question! This is the right question. Keep asking like this: "Yes it is true that I have bad karma, but still I am God's child, why doesn't God forgive my flaws and grant me Liberation!'. The answer is this: God is ready to give you everything you ask and even more. In fact, God is ready to give you Liberation. But guess what, we all have said No to God. We have said 'Please do not give me what I want, I want to experience this'. In reality, you have chosen the experience that you have obtained. We have said 'I want to watch the movie fully, please do not spoil the suspense!'

Comment: The moment we are ready to accept God's grace, it flows like the rain into us. That is why all religions emphasize on Love or 'Accepting yourself as you are!'. The Christians say 'accept that you are Saved and accept the Lord's grace'. The Vaishnavas say 'just acknowledge that you have surrendered to Vishnu and He will liberate You :)'. The advaitins say 'Simply accept yourself as God, everything else is illusion'. All the rites and  rituals are actually meant to expand and open our Mind and lead us to the understanding that we are worthy of being Loved. but sometimes humanity loses to dogmas.

Comment: That's because of MAYA. He is indirectly saying us via Pundits and Astrologers. As we cannot ask the basic question " Why did God send us here?" unless we come out of MAYA or break the wall of ignorance. This can't be answered to the point as we are in His MAYA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Question can never have to the point answer, Going in depth in this issue will put different view and idea.I will like to answer on my perception of GOD.

As you had mentioned

> we are god's children.

Thinking practically..

suppose a person have 100 rightfull heir (sons) to his Property, But his dilemma is to whom he should give his house ( suppose he cant give his House to all his 100 son), Now to decide he need some parameters to decide whom to transfer his House.

considering the above example as situation of God.

everyone can't have everything,if any body plans to have a thing which is not common to everyone he need to show his strong desire and ability to have that thing.

As we know all material thing in this world doesn't apply to real self (The Soul),So we need to show our will power by showing our strong hold on soul,which is not affected by the materialistic nature of world.
These were the reason Sadhus ,Rishi muni,Warriors earlier perform **Asceticism** or **Mortification of the flesh**, to get pleasure for soul.

But things had eventually changed ,earlier penance was done for soul,eg people used to ask for Moksha, Divine knowledge which were attributes of soul.

but these days we ask everything (mostly materialistic things) from God. like, Promotion,Passing exam etc etc.

*please do edit this answer, if you think anything is wrongly written*

Comment: You should cite sources.