# Why this kind of Akashvani for Kamsa?

Tags: vishnu, krishna

I am looking for a right answer, why did the Akashvani said that Kamsa was going to be killed by the 8th son of Devaki and Vasudev. He loved his sister so deeply that he himself drove the chariot. He married Devaki with such a pompous way that anyone could imagine, Well to say. None of the text reveal that kamsa was evil and cruel before akashvani. He used to go out for wars every now and then, that was his ambition but there is nothing I read about reason that made such a horrifying announcement by Akashvaani?

Comment: Probably the logic or [reincarnations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaya-Vijaya) might set right here: *Vishnu's gatekeeprs Jay/Vijay were cursed to be taking birth on earth and getting killed by Vishnu himself. In case of Varaha/Narasimha they were Hiranyaksha/Hiranyakashipu. In case of Rama they were Ravana/Kumbhkarna and in case of Krishna they were Kamsa/Shishupala.* Means, Kamsa was supposed to be killed and hence the Akashvani.

Comment: @iammilind No, Kamsa wasn't an incarnation of Jaya or Vijaya.  As brijabasi says in his answer, Kamsa was a rebirth of the demon Kalanemi whom Vishnu killed.  Jaya and Vijaya were born as Shishupala and his brother Dantavakra, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2042/36 Krishna killed Dantavakra when Dantavakra came to Dwaraka to kill Krishna in order to avenge his brother's death.

Comment: A possible reason could be so that Kamsa could imprison Devaki and Vasudeva and kill their six children, who were actually children of Rishi Marichi cursed to be born as humans and killed by Kalanemi, who incarnated as Kamsa.

Answer (score 2):

Kamsa was an asura named Kalanemi in his previous birth (see Bhagavatam 10.1.28 [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/1/68) or 10.51.41 [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/51/41)). So his loving demeanor was highly superficial - once his asuric pride was offended he manifested his real nature and didn't even hesitate to attempt murdering his beloved sister on the day of her marriage. Great Bhagavata commentator Vishvanath Chakravarti answers your question in his commentary on 10.1.34. The summary of his explanations is that one of the goals of Krishna avatara was to kill Kamsa (Kalanemi), but the devas started worrying that since Kamsa is so affectionate to Devaki, Krishna may not wish to kill him without any cause, so they announced the message to Kamsa to reveal his true nature. But this akash-vani they also conveyed to Vasudeva and Devaki fearlessness by letting them know that the Lord will soon appear as their son.