# Who were Jay and Vijay?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, brahma

I have heard that there were two brothers named 'Jay' and 'Vijay'. I have also heard that they were cursed by Lord Brahma's sons. So,what is the story of Jay and Vijay?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here. You can search for Jaya and Vijaya in the search bar.

Comment: @Shivam: The story of Jaya and Vijaya is posted here. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/was-ravana-actually-a-villain-or-a-devotee-of-lord-vishnu/2042#2042

Comment: @Shivam you mean their birth and how they got appointed as GateKeepers of Vishnu?

Answer (score 2):

Jay and Vijay were two gatekeepers of Lord Vishnu. One day Lord Brahma's four sons named 'Sanaka,Sananda,Sanatana and Sanatkumara' had visited to Ksheer Sagar to met with Lord Vishnu. Due to their strength tapas,they appeared to be mere children and they were very famous Brahmins. Jay and Vijay had stopped Brahma's sons because they thought that the Brahmins were children and Jay and Vijay also made fun of Brahma's sons. The sons of Lord Brahma became so much angry and they gave a curse to Jay and Vijay that they will be separate from Lord Vishnu. Jay and Vijay were so afraid. Lord Vishnu came and told Brahma's sons to forgive Jay and Vijay. Then Lord Brahma's sons told Vishnu that they cannot free Jay and Vijay from their curse. Lord Vishnu gave Jay and Vijay two options. One was that if Jay and Vijay want to live with Vishnu,so,they have to take six births as Lord Vishnu's devotee. Another option was that if Jay and Vijay did not want to chose first option,so,they have to take three births as Lord Vishnu's enemies. Jay and Vijay had chosen the second option. After that Jay and Vijay were born as Lord Vishnu's enemies. Jay and Vijay's first birth was Hiranyakashyap and Hiranyaksha. Their second birth was Ravana and Kumbhakarna. Their third and last birth was Shishupal and Dantavakra.